# SVN. Retry interactive conflict resolution

Tags: svn

If I do an update in SVN that results in a conflict SVN offers me a range of options for handling the conflict of each file, including accepting either file, launching an external merge program, or postponing the conflict resolution.

If I choose to postpone resolving the conflict, how do I get SVN to repeat the conflict resolution process. Specifically how do I get SVN to re-offer the choice of accepting either file or launching an external merge tool?

[Update] In response to Thomas and Skippy's replies.

Thanks for the answers. So as it appeared SVN doesn't have a command to rerun the conflict resolution process. Personally I think that sucks.

One of the choices of the SVN conflict resolution process is the option to select which file I wish to keep. Doing this within SVN has the advantage that SVN itself then handles the copying and deleting of the appropriate files, this precludes the need for the user to mess with the filesystem directly and reduces the potential for making a mistake.

Another choice the SVN conflict resolution process offers is the option to launch an external merge editor. The editor that is launched and how it is setup can be configured within the SVN config file. This is very convenient as it means the user doesn't have to manually load the three files into the external merge editor.

Apart from that it simply hasn't been coded is there any reason SVN doesn't offer the facility to restart the conflict resolution process? (Perhaps by calling svn resolve with just a path argument). Another reason this would be nice is that it might offer the choice of resolving one file, or function recursively on a working copy, or subtree within a working copy.

Comment: Exactly, it kills the convenience of the non-interactive option, to save time finishing the merge and then resolving. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In svn 1.8.8
if you run "svn resolve " on file of interest, svn will offer interactive conflict resolution

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't get it to re-offer the choice. You have no choice but the following ones :

> - Merge the conflicted text “by hand” (by examining and editing the
>     conflict markers within the file).
> - Copy one of the temporary files on top of your working file.
> - Run svn revert  to throw away all of your local changes.
>
> Once you've resolved the conflict, you need to let Subversion know by
>   running svn resolved. This removes the three temporary files and
>   Subversion no longer considers the file to be in a state of
>   conflict.[6]

(from http://chestofbooks.com/computers/revision-control/subversion-svn/Postponing-Conflict-Resolution-Tour-Cycle-Resolve-Pending.html )

Comment: There's a 4th option - you can manually launch the merge program with the `.mine`, `.rOLDREV` and `.rNEWREV` files, and with the base filename (the versioned file) as merge output. This is what svn does when it launches the external merge program.

Answer (score 0):

SVN won't ask you again. However, when you run `svn stat` from the command line you should see a list of files in conflict. These will be marked with a "C", just like if there is a modified file it comes up with a "M" or if there is a file that hasn't been added it comes up with a "?".

Now you have to manually run [`svn resolve`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.resolve.html) on each of the files.